# Get the data type which has been converted from void*?

Tags: c++

I have a function which has 3 parameters. the third parameter's data type is `void*`, and there are two types of data that can be passed through it either `std::string` or `FILE*`.

```
bool MainDialog::readDataFromUrl(const std::string url, const std::string parameter, void *reply) {
    CURL *curl;
    bool status;
    curl = curl_easy_init();
    if(curl){
        std::string fullUrl = url +  parameter;
        curl_easy_reset(curl);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, fullUrl.c_str());
        if(typeid(reply) != typeid(FILE*)){
            curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, &MainDialog::writeFunction);
        }
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, reply);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10L);
        if(curl_easy_perform(curl) != CURLE_OK){
            status = false;
        }
        curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
        status = true;
    }
    return status;
}
```

When usage:

```
FILE *file;
file = fopen("jsonData.txt", "wb");
this->readDataFromUrl("http://example.com?api=data", "", (FILE*)file);
```

And the following part of code checks the data type and decide if it's `std::string` does something and if it's `FILE*` does another thing.

```
if(typeid(reply) != typeid(FILE*))
   curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, &MainDialog::writeFunction);
```

**Is it possible to get the data type which converted to from** `void*`?

Comment: A `std::string*`, i.e. a pointer, surely?

Comment: Why don't you write 2 functions, `bool MainDialog::readDataFromUrl(const std::string url, const std::string parameter, FILE *reply)` and `bool MainDialog::readDataFromUrl(const std::string url, const std::string parameter, std::string reply)` and let overload resolution do its job?

Comment: This is C++, so you can have functions with the same name but different types of arguments.

Comment: @Bathsheba: Yes.

Comment: You can't extract any type information from a `void *`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, you can't get that information back, which is why people say that casting everything to `void*` to cram it into one function is not type-safe. It is said that you have "erased" the type.

Instead, pass a [`std::variant<std::string, FILE*>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant).

If you are pre-C++17, pass a [`boost::variant<std::string, FILE*>`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_64_0/doc/html/variant.html).

A "variant" is an implementation of a "tagged union", which does what you are doing, but in a type-safe manner; the variant will be able to tell you which kind of object is actually stored.

An alternative would be to have a fourth parameter that is an enum (or some other kind of "tag") that describes how the third parameter should be interpreted:

```
enum reply_type_t {
   STRING,
   FILE_PTR
};

bool MainDialog::readDataFromUrl(
   const std::string& url,
   const std::string& parameter,
   void* reply,
   replyType_t replyType
);
```

Unfortunately this depends on the person calling `readDataFromUrl` to "get it right". We can help it along with a couple of new overloads:

```
bool MainDialog::readDataFromUrl(
   const std::string& url,
   const std::string& parameter,
   const std::string& reply
)
{
   return readDataFromUrl(url, parameter, (void*)&reply, STRING);
}

bool MainDialog::readDataFromUrl(
   const std::string& url,
   const std::string& parameter,
   const FILE* reply
)
{
   return readDataFromUrl(url, parameter, (void*)reply, FILE_PTR);
}
```

Now your caller only needs to directly pass the correct argument, and the tagging is done for you automatically.

Seriously, though, just use a variant.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot do it: `typeid` operator lets you distinguish among dynamic types of the object at run-time only with polymorphic types, and `FILE` is *not* a polymorphic type. In your code, `typeid` would end up with the type identifier of `void*`, which is not going to help at all.

You have several approaches to address this requirement:

- Make overloads of your function for different types that it can accept, or
- Make an `enum` with different types, and pass it along with `void*` as a separate parameter, or
- Make a `union` with an `enum` tag, make an instance of this union, and pass a pointer as `void*` to the function, or
- Always unwrap the reply, i.e. read `FILE*` into `std::string`

The first approach is ideal if you can change the signature of the function to be type-specific.

Comment: @nwp: In this context, it is. You're giving it an expression, and if the expression's type is not polymorphic, it will only describe `void*`, which is utterly useless.

Answer (score 0):

No, it's not possible to get the actual type data from void *. `typeid` operator works properly only on polymorphic types which are class/struct types that have at least one virtual method.

Comment: `typeid` works just fine on non-polymorphic types and `typeid(reply)` gives you the `std::type_info` for `void *`, which is merely unhelpful.

Comment: Yes, of course it works on built-in types, there's just not much use for that when you actually need a runtime type identification which seems to be the case in this question.

Answer (score 0):

No. Once you cast it away to `void *`, type information is lost. The usual approach here is to pass a structure of known type (so you can cast it back safely), and store inside it the file pointer or the string, along with an enum field to let you know which of the two is the valid one.